# storing tweets in mysql from streaming api using java

Tags: java, mysql, twitter

I'm using twitter4j's streaming API to collect tweets. I'm doing this on java platform. I'm getting a stream of tweets at console but can't store.

```
public void onStatus(Status status) {
                              try
             {
               String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
               String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/twitterapi";
               Class.forName(myDriver);
               Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "twitterapi", "");

               String query = " insert into tweets"
               + "(tweet_id,tweet_text,screen_name)" + " values" 
                       + "('" + status.getId() + "','" +
                          status.getText() + "', '" +
                          status.getUser().getScreenName() +"')";  

               Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
               statement.executeUpdate(query);
               conn.close();

             }
             catch (Exception e)
                              {
               System.err.println("Got an exception!");
               System.err.println(e.getMessage());
             }
             System.out.println("onStatus @" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + status.getText());
        }
```

Please consider every other thing to be correct since that's already working.

Comment: What happens when you try to store? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Looks like `author_id` column is missing from the `VALUES` in the `INSERT` query.

Comment: what is the exception you are getting? please state it clearly

Comment: Also, you appear to build a string of SQL and never execute it. Have a look at https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-insert-a-record/

Comment: No, I don't get any exception. Even, if I put some testing code like `System.out.println("l");` in try block, it gets printed on console. @DaveH

Comment: oh! that was a silly mistake(I wanted to have author_id earlier), I removed author_id, it's still not working. @Yohannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `insert` you have a different number of columns to values.  You are not specifying the author_id.

In addition, as DaveH noticed, you're not actually running the SQL command against the server.

Comment: I edited my code. now, i'm getting exception **Got an exception!
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's supporters, the vote leading to #LetLizSpeak was a textbook case of males sile' at line 1**   @DaveH

Comment: You have an apostrophe in your values and you're not escaping them.

Comment: Exactly, this is the problem. But, how should I do it here, I mean on `status.getText()`

Comment: Replace all the apostrophes with either '' (two apostrophes) or `\'`.  e.g. `status.getText().replace("'", "\\'")`.